# Pinia lost reactivity when using it in library mode

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vite, pinia, npm-package

i'm currently trying to create a library out of an existing project, that should export a component with a "flow" inside it (eg. Imagine the library as an iframe replace, so importing the library should give the possibility to import a component that handle it's own flow, data, etc..).

So, the pinia instance is shared across the `Host` and the `Library`.

The `Host` has also a Vuex instance installed on it, we will see it later on.

## Library

`Node: v16.17.0`

`npm: v8.15.0`

`Library` exports a default method `install` that manage to apply all the plugins that needs in order to execute correctly.

```vue
export default {
    install(Vue) {
        // Vue.use(...) Vue custom plugins that install only prototypes
        Vue.use(CustomRouterPlugin); // install a plugin that uses store inside it, it replace the VueRouter functionality with our state based management
        Vue.component("LibraryCore", LibraryCore);
    },
};
```

It also exports all the stores used by the `Library` and `LibraryCore` component:

```js
import * as Stores from '@/stores'

// install method exports

export { Stores, LibraryCore };
```

> index.js

```js
import { useAStore } from "./astore";
import { useBStore } from "./bstore";
import { useCStore } from "./cstore";
// continue ...
export {
    useAStore,
    useBStore,
    useCStore
};
```

> stores/index.js

All the stores in `Library` are pretty the same:

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

import { routes } from "@/router";


export const useRouterStore = defineStore("router", {
    state: () => ({
        routeName: "home",
        routes: routes, // {'home': { name: 'home',component: Object | VueComponent, etc..} }
    }),
    getters: {
        currentRoute: function () {
            return this.routes[this.routeName];
        },
    },
    actions: {
        setCurrentRoute: function (routeName) {

            if (!this.routes[routeName]) {
                throw new Error(`Route ${routeName} does not exist`);
            }
           this.routeName = routeName;
        },
    },
});
```

> stores/namestore.js

This is the `Library` vite config file:

```js
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import { createVuePlugin as vue2 } from "vite-plugin-vue2";
import path from "path";
/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */

export default ({ mode }) => {
    let buildConfigs = {
        brotliSize: true,
    };

    if (mode.includes("library")) {
        buildConfigs.lib = {
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
            name: "cf-components",
            formats: ["es"],
            fileName: (format) => `cf-components.${format}.js`,
        };
        buildConfigs.rollupOptions = {
            external: [
                'vue',
                'pinia',
                'vue-router'
            ],

            output: {
                dir: "dist",
                globals: {
                    vue: "Vue",
                },
            },
        };
    }

    return defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            vue2({
                jsx: true,
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
                vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm.js",
            },
            dedupe: ["vue"],
        },
        build: buildConfigs,
    });
};
```

> vite.config.js

And the `Library` package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "@company/cf-components",
    "version": "0.2.10",
    "private": false,
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "repo url"
    },
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "main": "dist/cf-components.cjs.js",
    "module": "dist/cf-components.es.js",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "require": "./dist/cf-components.cjs.js",
            "import": "./dist/cf-components.es.js"
        },
        "./css": "./dist/style.css"
    },
    "sideEffects": false,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build-staging": "vite build --mode staging",
        "build-library": "vite build --mode library",
        "build": "vite build",
        "serve": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@formkit/auto-animate": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
        "@lottiefiles/vue-lottie-player": "^1.0.9",
        "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.2",
        "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
        "dompurify": "^2.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "marked": "^4.1.0",
        "tippy.js": "^6.3.7",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.28.2",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "js-cookie": "^3.0.1"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.7.10",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
        "pinia": "^2.0.22",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/markdown-it": "^12.2.3",
        "@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl": "^0.1.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
        "postcss": "^8.4.16",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.13",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
        "vite": "^3.2.0",
        "vite-plugin-vue2": "^2.0.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
    }
}
```

> package.json

All components inside `Library` use mapState,mapAction and mapStores from `pinia`.

Running the `Library` as a normal Vue app using `npm run dev` works fine.

## Host

`Node: v16.17.0`

`npm: v8.15.0`

`Host` is a laravel application using `laravel mix: 8.15.0`

The `Library` package is imported using `npm link` for local development.

The `Host` imports `Library` and install it's plugin:

```js
import style from '@company/cf-components/css';
import { createPinia, PiniaVuePlugin } from 'pinia';
import LibraryPlugin, { AxiosPiniaPlugin, CfStores } from '@company/cf-components';

const pinia = createPinia();
Vue.use(PiniaVuePlugin); // imported from pinia
pinia.use(AxiosPiniaPlugin); // custom pinia plugin that inject a custom axios instance
Vue.use(LibraryPlugin);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    store: store, // the host's vuex store
    i18n: i18n,
    pinia: pinia,
    render: (h) => h(App),
});
```

> app.js

And use the `Library` component inside a Test component:

```vue
<template lang="">
    <LibraryCore class="mt-32" :isPluginValue="true"></LibraryCore>
    <!-- :isPluginValue tell the library component to act as a Plugin, so it doesn't use the VueRouter but our custom made Router based on state -->
</template>
<script>
import style from '@company/cf-components/css';
import { mapStores } from 'pinia';

export default {
 name: "Test"
};
</script>
```

In `Host` the `LibraryCore` is rendered correctly.

Also the `Vue DevTools` shows `pinia`'s stores correctly with also the `Vuex`'s store.

When an action that should mutate the `Library`'s store is called, the values inside the devtools pinia's store change correctly, but the changes are not reflected inside the components.

### Example:

mapping the "setCurrentRoute" action inside the component, and calling it, actually change the state value from the default 'home' to the one given as parameter.

Also the getter "currentRoute", inside dev tools, change accordingly the state "routeName" and returns the expected element.

But it looks like that this changes are not reactive, and doesn't reflect in the component computed proprieties.

`...mapState(useRouterStore, ['currentRoute'])`

### What did i tried

- I've tried to create and instantiate a *different* `pinia` store inside `Host` and use it from an `Host`'s component. And it looks like that when using it inside an `Host` component it's reactivity works.
- I've instantiate a `Library`'s exported store inside an `Host`'s component and tried to show a state value inside the component, and modifying that state value inside the dev tools seems to not be reactive also.

### What i expect

The desired behavior is that when a `Library`'s store value is mutated, the mutation should be reflected to the `Library`'s component making it reactive and changing accordingly to the state values.